# Google.com Admob shows WRONG admob/iAd mediation, what's correct way?

Tags: ios, admob, linker-errors, iad, xcode6.1

I followed Google's Admob/iAd mediation step by step. I only end up getting an error. This is the EXACT error. I copied and pasted from Xcode.

```
Ld /Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tap\ .app/Tap\  normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Tap  copy 7"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Tap\ copy\ 7/LibAdapterIAd-1.0.0 -L2 -L/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Tap\ copy\ 7/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.2 -F/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Intermediates/Leap\ Up.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tap\ Up.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Leap\ Up.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -lGoogleAdMobAds -framework StoreKit -framework MessageUI -framework EventKitUI -framework EventKit -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -framework AVFoundation -framework AdSupport -framework iAd -lAdapterIAd -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -weak_framework GameKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Intermediates/Tap\ Up.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tap\ Up.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Tap\ Up_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/RobShi/Desktop/Robfile/Tap-hleybktumiggijftdbmrtsiuozcy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tap\ Up.app/Tap\ 

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Tap  copy 7/LibAdapterIAd-1.0.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L2'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/RobShi/Desktop/Tap  copy 7/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.2'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Xcode 6.1. I'm creating a game with storyboards. Google's mediation isn't working. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

Click on your project (targets)
Click on Build Settings
Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths
And the second error, sorry i can help you out with that one. Hope someone else can help you out.